# Formulario hijo como pagina

Tags: c#, windows-forms, devexpress

Necesito llamar un formulario hijo dentro de un formulario padre, pero quiero que el formulario hijo se vea como una pagina, se me ocurre que este dentro de un control DockPanel. ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: no contengas formularios dentro de controles, crea User Control, los cuales puedes instanciar y poner dentro de Panel1.Controls.Add()

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas Paneles o controles que contienen otros controles aplica dento de estos `User Control`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma podras hacer facilmente

```
UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
```

El `UserControl` es muy parecido a un `Form` solo que sin los bordes

[How to use User Controls to create MDI WinForm Applications](http://www.dountsis.com/general/how-to-use-user-controls-to-create-mdi-winform-applications.php)